# Where in Magento admin can I set/change expiry time for the cart?

Tags: magento2, product, shopping-cart, adobe-commerce

Where in Magento admin can I set expiry time for products in the cart? Currently, the product is not going to stay in the cart for more than 24 hours once a cart is abondoned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Admin > Store > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart > Quote Lifetime (days)

[image]

You can add time here. Thank you!